# How do I configure ADB for the Huawei U8650 on Windows?

Tags: adb, windows, huawei-u8650

I have an Huawei U8650 smartphone. And, as I understand, I need system device drivers for it to be able to develop and debug applications for it using Windows.

On Linux this is as simple as just typing an identifier number in a few places and I'm able to run and debug applications. However I can't seem to find the appropriate drivers to be able to do this on Windows.

Does anyone have any idea how to set it up on a Windows machine?

Comment: Take a look at the [Universal Android USB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/), or check the Huawei website for specific drivers. That's the corresonding thing to setting up UDEV on Linux ;)

Comment: It looks ok so far, need to get my environment up and running now and I'll let you know if this worked

Comment: OK, I made it an answer you then can accept if it works out. Good luck. // A hint: As development questions are off-topic here (see our [help center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for details), your question will be "put on hold" soon. Please keep that in mind for subsequent questions: this one most likely could be re-phrased to be on-topic again, real development questions are better fit on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). See also: [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575)

Comment: To VCers: ADB driver issues for windows and development are just a coincidence here, power users also may have the same issue, hence: Not off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pendant to the UDEV setup you describe in your question, Windows needs a special driver. Until recently that meant the manufacturer had to provide one matching to the device; but luckily we now have the [Universal Android USB Driver](http://adbdriver.com/), which should work for most devices. If that doesn't work for yours, you need to check with Huawei for a specific driver.

Comment: Glad to read – enjoy :)